Is this list of Formal Symbols complete? Which versions have unprotected Formal Symbols?
Formal Symbols are protected against being assigned values, making them handy for avoiding name collisions for things like fit parameters and pattern matching. Because formal symbols (and others) like \[FormalA] are immediatly replaced with their character (which looks much nicer in the Front End than \[FormalA]), i found it a bit annoying to figure out the best way of finding them. SymbolName[\[FormalA]] returns exactly the same renderred character as the input, though the input is a Symbol and the output a String. Characters[SymbolName[\[FormalA]]] returns again the same thing. Shortcuts for writing these symbols are  ([using] (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html.en) Esc for :,:$a: gives \[FormalA] and $Omega gives \[FormalOmega] while :$CapitalXi: gives \[FormalCapitalXi.
But I figured out a way to get what looks to be a decently compherhensive list.
The following returns a list of 168 names when run in a fresh kernel in version 14.0. Are there any other symbols which are intended to be used in a similar way?
formalNames=Select[Names["System`*"],StringContainsQ[ToString[FullForm[#]],"\\[Formal"]&]

I would also like to point out that István Zachar's comment on this question appears to be obsolete, at least for the example \[FormalPhi]. this can be seen by inspecting the following:
Table[{n, ToString[FullForm[n]], Attributes[Evaluate[Symbol[n]]]}, {n,formalNames}]

Noticing that was actually the main reason I posted this question, since it indicates that formal symbols might be safer to use than I originally thought, at least for 14.0. Are others aware of when this changed?
Not only formal symbols have this sometimes irritating tendency to constantly render in a form that is non ASCII i.e. PrintableASCIIQ[string] is False.   See this list of named chracters

LouisB has an answer to list all named characters. Looking at the attributes of all these characters, it seems that only the Formal* family has the attribute Protected (which is what you want if I understand correctly).
